# MySQL Not Turning On

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, amazon-ec2, django, socket

I have an amazon ec2 instance running on the Amazon Linux AMI and its a micro instance. I wanted to install Django onto my server so I entered these commands

```
wget http://www.mlsite.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/go
wget http://www.mlsite.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/django.conf
chmod 744 go
./go
```

So after I was done, I ran `sudo service httpd restart` and `sudo service mysqld restart`

and This is what came up for mysqld:

```
Stopping mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
```

So I deleted the django files `/usr/local/python2.6.8/site-packages/django_registration.egg`
and 
I tried finding the error and I found out that in my 
`/etc/my.cnf` for the socket, it said `socket=/var/lock/subsys/mysql.sock` so I went to `/var/lock/subsys/` and there was no `mysql.sock`. I tried creating one using vim but it still didn't work. Then I checked the error log and it said

```
120712 20:33:11 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
120712 20:33:15 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
```

### **UPDATE:**

I entered these commands:

```
cd /var/lib/mysql/
touch mysql.sock
chmod +x mysql.sock
chown mysql:mysql -R *
```

And it still didn't work...

So I am pretty much lost right now. I know it has something to do with `mysql.sock`

If you might know a reason why this was caused could you please let me know? I have a wordpress site on my server, so i kind of need MySQL to work. Thanks!

Comment: You need to find out why mysqld failed to start.  Check in your mysql or system logs.  Once mysql is running there will be a /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Comment: i can't check my mysql. every time I type mysql it says ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: @ShalinShah Yes, we know that you're getting that error. Look through your logs to find out why.

Comment: Any particular reason you're not installing an official repo Django package?

Comment: Did you look over the script (go) that you ran? It makes several assumptions may not hold true on your setup. The notable one being an ebs volume on /dev/sda4 - which the scripts attempts to mount and then tries to move your MySQL directory to /mnt/ebs/mysql (it also changes your my.cnf accordingly). If you don't have the necessary EBS volume, my.cnf will have an invalid path in it. Revert the changes to /etc/my.cnf and hopefully MySQL will start. As an aside the script is trying to install Django 1.0 (current version is 1.4.2).

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Not Working](http://serverfault.com/questions/439587/mysql-not-working)

Comment: If MySQL failed to start why are you surprised that its socket doesn't exist? It will only be created after a *successful* start. Do not manually create sockets. When you find and rectify the problem preventing MySQL from starting the socket will be created and will function as it's supposed to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inspecting the `go` script you downloaded and executed, I found the following lines:

```
# Change the MySQL data directory
sed -e 's!/var/lib/mysql$!/mnt/ebs/mysql!' -i /etc/my.cnf
```

This effectively changes your mysql data directory (`datadir` setting), so you can't access any previously created database (like the wordpress database).

As a wild guess, I would think that the mysqld can't access `/mnt/ebs/mysql` and therefore doesn't start. Try to change it back to `/var/lib/mysql`. However, this might interfere with your django. If you get the django configured mysql to run, you can always add a second my.cnf with another name and other tcp port and run two MySQL servers with different configurations.

The socket error message is about the MySQL server not running. Do not try to emulate the socket by putting a file in its way.

The `go` script also makes some more changes to my.cnf that could be a problem. Have a look at the go file yourself and try to undo the changes made.

If nothing of the above helps, you can try to start the mysqld process from command line by hand, using the same arguments as the service script does, plus an added `--verbose` and post its output.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out thanks to @escitalopram so I will accept his answer! Ok, django changed my MySQL data directory from `/var/lib/mysql` to `/mnt/ebs/mysql` in my `/etc/my.cnf`, so in my `/etc/my.cnf`, it said

`datadir=/mnt/ebs/mysql` and I changed it to `datadir=/var/lib/mysql`. And everything worked fine. I restarted MySQL hoping for the red [FAILED] message but I got an [OK]. Also, my socket was messed up in `/etc/my.cnf` but I had already fixed that!

Answer (score -1):

i had the same situation on amazon e2c server

i did the same:

```
 cd /var/lib/mysql/
    sudo touch mysql.sock
    sudo chmod +x mysql.sock
    sudo chown mysql:mysql -R *
```

reboot the server,
 then:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

check mysql:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

note, this will not fix the problem. but it will give you the chance to access the data and move to a reliable server